# When reading from a file stream image get flipped -90

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, filestream

I'm trying to load an image in a local path to a Silverlight image control. This is an out of browser application. When I load the image using a stream it's always flipped upside down.

Any idea why? This happens for large images only.

`FileName` here gives the full path to local file system, like `C:\imageFullPath\image.jpg`.

Please help. Following is the code.

------ In Model side------------------------

```
public BitmapImage DisplayImage
{
    get
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileName))
        {
            var b = new BitmapImage();
            b.SetSource(System.IO.File.OpenRead(FileName));                     
            return b;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

------ In Silverlight View side------------------------

```
<Image Source="{Binding DisplayImage, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="450" Height="250" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

What i see when debugging

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`BMP` are [normally stored "upside-down"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_array_.28bitmap_data.29) with the pixels in reverse order from bottom to top, but can use a negative height in the file header to indicate the image is stored top-to-bottom, so perhaps you have such an image.

Does this happen with all images, or just that one?

You could try changing the way the image is loaded, using a `Uri` in the constructor instead of calling `SetSource()` with a `Stream`, as it may account for the header and read the file differently:

```
var b = new BitmapImage(new Uri(FileName));                    
return b;
```

Or, if that doesn't help, you can [apply a transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348048.aspx) to flip every image, but that doesn't solve the underlying problem:

```
<Image Source="{Binding DisplayImage, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="450" Height="250" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

This happens with only large images not only this one but every large image. I already tried first approach var b = new BitmapImage(new Uri(FileName));  
but that just return empty image. 

Second one isn't practical for me since i would have to decide all these in model side rather than in xaml. Any other ideas?